# When to use device and when to use constant address space qualifier in metal shading language?

Tags: swift, 3d, metal

I know that device address space is used when indexing a buffer and constant address space is used when many invocations of the function will access the same portion of the buffer. But I am still not very clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Based on this [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

### device Address Space

> The device address space name refers to buffer memory objects
>   allocated from the device memory pool that are both readable and
>   writeable. A buffer memory object can be declared as a pointer or
>   reference to a scalar, vector or userdefined structure. In an app,
>   Metal API calls allocate the memory for the buffer object, which
>   determines the actual size of the buffer memory. Some examples are:

```
// An array of a float vector with four components.

device float4 *color;
struct Foo {
float a[3];
int b[2];
}
// An array of Foo elements.
device Foo *my_info;
```

> Since you always allocate texture objects from the device address
>   space, you do not need the device address attribute for texture types.

### constant Address Space

> The constant address space name refers to buffer memory objects
>   allocated from the device memory pool but are read-only. Variables in
>   program scope must be declared in the constant address space and
>   initialized during the declaration statement. The initializer(s)
>   expression must be a core constant expression. Variables in program
>   scope have the same lifetime as the program, and their values persist
>   between calls to any of the compute or graphics functions in the
>   program.

`constant float samples[] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f };`

> Pointers or references to the constant address space are allowed as
>   arguments to functions. Writing to variables declared in the constant
>   address space is a compile-time error. Declaring such a variable
>   without initialization is also a compile-time error. To decide which
>   address space (device or constant) a read-only buffer passed to a
>   graphics or kernel function uses, look at how the buffer is accessed
>   inside the graphics or kernel function. The constant address space is
>   optimized for multiple instances executing a graphics or kernel
>   function accessing the same location in the buffer. Some examples of
>   this access pattern are accessing light or material properties for
>   lighting / shading, matrix of a matrix array used for skinning, filter
>   weight accessed from a filter weight array for convolution. If
>   multiple executing instances of a graphics or kernel function are
>   accessing the buffer using an index such as the vertex ID, fragment
>   coordinate, or the thread position in grid, the buffer must be
>   allocated in the device address space.

Comment: Thank you very much that is an amazing explanation!

Comment: This doesn't really cover the case of `const device` though.  If `const` is enough to define *read only* to the shader then why do we need `constant` as it appears to be the same as `const device`.